# Up button navigation with multiple top destinations and subgraphs -- all children of subgraph are also top level

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

The nav graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.hanafey.android.waterstats.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"
        />

    <!-- ......   -->

    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/navigation_graph_setup"
        android:label="Setup"
        app:startDestination="@id/navigation_setup"
        >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_setup"
            android:name="com.hanafey.android.waterstats.ui.setup.SetupFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_setup"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_setup"
            />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_find_or_create_results_sheet"
            android:name="com.hanafey.android.waterstats.ui.setup.FindOrCreateResultsSheetFragment"
            android:label="Find Or Create Results Sheet"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_find_or_create_results_sheet"
            />
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_show_results_sheet_details"
            android:name="com.hanafey.android.waterstats.ui.setup.FindOrCreateResultsSheetDetailsFragment"
            android:label="Find Or Create Result Sheet Details"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_file_find_or_initialize_result"
            />
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

The action bar is setup as follows:

```
val topLevelDid = setOf(
    R.id.navigation_home,
    R.id.navigation_septic,
    R.id.navigation_notifications,
    R.id.navigation_graph_setup,
)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(topLevelDid)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

The problem is all members of subgraph `R.id.navigation_graph_setup` become top level, and no up button is displayed. The desired behaviour is only the start destination of the subgraph is top level.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, do not mark the subgraph as top level. Instead mark the starting destination of the subraph as top level. This means you need to be consistent in the graph xml and the code. It would be better if specifying the subgraph as top in the code instead set the starting destination as top, but this is complicated if the starting destination is changed at run time.

The code in 'androidx.navigation.ui.AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener' shows how top level is inferred by looking at a destination and then recursively looking at all its parents.